# How to use Stellar to Build International Remittance app

Tags: stellar-core

I want to build a money remittance app using stellar as a middleware.If a person sends money how can a receiver withdraw money ?

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of the international remittance, Stellar is the transport layer and single source of truth for loosely connected financial organization.

It works quite similar to SWIFT. Stellar does not transmit any money or real-world values; it rather allows two independent parties to make a virtual transaction and ensure validity and consistency. Financial institutions ("anchors") that operate on Stellar network deal with clients and fiat payments.

Right now you can transfer money from say, Los Angeles to Warsaw using existing anchors. A user purchases tethered USD using a credit card or bank transfer, automatically exchanges it for tethered EUR, and transfers money to the recipient which can remit the EUR credit through the Tempo bank.

The primary goal of the remittance applications is to make the transfer as frictionless as possible by automating deposit/withdrawal operations and provide the liquidity. Independent anchors operate on the same open network, so the more financial institutions and remittance providers are connected, the more profitable and versatile is the overall remittance landscape - the network effect in action.

Nobody controls the underlying transnational level (Stellar network); all transactions are transparent and retained forever. Therefore, independent parties can agree to use it as a universal intermediate exchange protocol.